# Remove numerical values which are lesser than preceding value

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, sed, grep

I have data in the following form:

```
      1      "there"
      ...
      23489  "abc"
      23490  "hello"
      23491  "hi"
      2      "def"
      23492  "stackoverflow"
```

I want to delete all the lines which start from a numerical value which is less than the preceding numeric value (i.e. I want to delete: 2 "def" as 2<23491 numerically)

I want my final output to look of the following form:

```
      1      "there"
      ...
      23489  "abc"
      23490  "hello"
      23491  "hi"
      23492  "stackoverflow"
```

I know I can do so programatically using a programming language like python..but is it possible to do the same using some linux command like sed, grep, etc

EDIT: The solutions to the questions are very elegant. Is it also possible to limit the length of the strings(present in second column) to say 3 with the present solutions. i.e. I want my output to look of the following form:

```
      1      "the"  
      ...
      23489  "abc"
      23490  "hel"
      23491  "hi"
      23492  "sta"
```

Thanks and sorry for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` you could say:

```
awk '{if ($1<prev){next}}{prev=$1}1' inputfile
```

For your input, it'd return:

```
$ awk '{if ($1<prev){next}}{prev=$1}1' inputfile
1      "there"
23489  "abc"
23490  "hello"
23491  "hi"
23492  "stackoverflow"
```

Saying `prev=$1` keeps the value in the first column in the variable `prev`.  `if ($1<prev){next}` checks if the first column is less than the previous value stored, then move to the next line else print (`1`).

EDIT: To limit the length of the string in the second column, you could say:

```
awk '{if ($1<prev){next}}{prev=$1; gsub("\"", "", $2); $2=substr($2,0,3);$2="\""$2"\""}1' inputfile
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a sweeter solution :)

Comment: @devnull Thanks a lot for the help. If possible, can you please explain it a bit..please

Comment: @AliceEverett Added the explanation above.

Comment: @devnull Is it also possible to limit the length of the strings to say 3 within the same command.. I understand that it is a somewhat separate question..but since your solution is a lot elegant..therefore I want to use user solution in combination with length restriction

Comment: @AliceEverett What do you mean by the length of the string?  The length of the first column in the input?

Comment: @devnull I have edited my question and am sorry for troubling you again

Comment: @devnull By length of the string I mean the length of the second column in the input

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make it work with this script, (not tested though so changes might be needed).

```
#!/bin/bash
PV="0"
for l in (data.txt)
do
    CV=$(echo $l | sed "s/[^[0-9]+]//g")
    if [ "$CV" -gt "$PV" ]
    then
      echo "${l}"
    fi
    PV=$CV
done
```